# ionic2- saving an array in storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to save an array of names in storage and retrieve them when user clicks a button. 
View has a textbox and a button using which user can enter any number of names and in the component, I fetch them and wanna save them to storage.
To retrieve the stored names, I have provided a button and user clicks on it, I wanna show all saved names (iterate it using a for loop or something)

When I try to save multiple names, I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.names.push is not a function
```

This error comes only when I try to save more than one name.

Here's the view:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-title>New category</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content class="addtrans">
   <button ion-button (click)="fetchAllNames()">Show Names!</button>

   <input type="text" id="name" #named>
   <button ion-button (click)="storeThisName(named.value)">Store This!</button>
</ion-content>
```

.ts file for this view is given below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  names =[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
  }

  fetchAllNames(){
    this.storage.ready().then(
      () => {
       // Or to get a key/value pair
       this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {
         console.log('Your age is', val);
       })
      });
  }

  storeThisName(name){
    console.log(name);
     this.storage.ready().then(
      () => {
        this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {
         console.log('Your age is', val);
         this.names= val;
         this.names.push(name);
         // set a key/value
         this.storage.set('name', this.names);
       })
      });
  }

}
```

What could be the possible error?
Note: app.module.ts file is configured properly.

Comment: what is the `val` returned from storage

Comment: you have `this.names= val;
         this.names.push(name);` what is datatype of val and name

Comment: May be `this.names= val;` assignment time, `val` could be undefined.. You could consider make it `this.names= val || [];`

Comment: both are strings @suraj

Comment: if you want names as array you cant do `this.names=val`..it should just be `this.names.push(val)`

Comment: val is supposed to be the array of names stored in Storage. @Aravind

Comment: if i do it that way, will it push the new name to the array of names already stored? @suraj

Comment: you mentioned both val and name are strings not array.. what does console.log(val) output?

Comment: Did you try doing what @PankajParkar suggested? Seems like the best answer

Comment: Yes, it worked. @misha130

Comment: @misha130 thanks for pointing out my comment. I added the answer to close this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `this.names= val;` line of code is making an issue. There if collection doesn't return by API then it is going to be undefined. So the exact next operation is going to be fail `this.names.push(name);`.

For such case you should change your code to below which will assign `[]` if there is no collection returned from server.

```
this.names= val || [];
this.names.push(name);
```